# What are cons to use jquery sifr plugin over original sifr 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, sifr, sifr3

If I'm alreadu using jquery library on site then should i use origional sifr or jquery plugin.

What are cons to use jquery sifr plugin over origional sifr 3?

jQuery sIFR Plugin

http://jquery.thewikies.com/sifr/known-issues

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but have you looked at the sifr alternatives? http://www.solidstategroup.com/what-we-think/a-comparison-between-sifr-cufon-and-font-face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a poorer implementation of sIFR 3, so I'd recommend against it. You can swap out the CSS selector engine in sIFR for the one from jQuery.